# How to invoke UAC(Elevation shield) Prompt while trying to open bootstrapper bundle exe in WIX

Tags: wix, bundle, bootstrapper, elevated-privileges, wix4

Not able to invoke UAC shield of the bootstrapper bundle .exe generated using WIX.UAC gets invoked when Install button is clicked.But I need to open UAC as soon as user double clicks the bundle .exe.

I tried WixBundleElevated in wix bundle wxs file in bal:Condition.This works fine.When user double click the exe bundle,error throws up like "you need admin priviledges".Instead of throwing error,I want to invoke UAC shield as soon as user double click the bundle exe.